# Angular - removing checkmark from radio button after deleting a default option

Tags: angular, typescript, radio-button

Angular:

On the front-end side of my application I have a form in which user can optionally add an item(s), and by using a radio button choose which one from those items will be a default one.

User can also delete the item selected as default, and after that the checkmark switches to another remaining item from table. Then that remaining item becomes a new default one. Like on the screen below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wblpz.png)

Is there any option to make that checkmark disappear with previously deleted item? Just to stay with f.e. 2 unselected options. Like on the screen below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QDAiX.png)

I want to force the application's user to click on option which has to be default - because it is connected with some other attributes set by clicking.

type script class responsible for that items:

```
protected getColumnsDef(): EditColumn[] {
    return [
        EditColumnCreator.createRadioUniqueEditor('defaultindicator', this.radioHeader),
        EditColumnCreator.createDropdownEditor('item', this.itemType)
            })
            .setUniqueDropdown(this.lookups.items)
    ];
}
```

html file responsible for the default field

```
<v6-radio *ngIf="!isAddNew"
           class="grid-edit-radio"
           [name]="itemName"
           [value]="node.id"
           [disabled]="!isEditionMode()"
           [model]="item.value"
           (modelChange)="onValueChange($event)">
</v6-radio>
```

I tried to set some attributes in scss file of radio button grid, find a class which is responsible for setting attributes to the object by clicking etc. but for now, without any success.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use [checked] property on your radio ?

i try it on Material and its works for me :

something like this :

```html
<v6-radio [checked]="Some Boolean value in TS"> </v6-radio>
```

hope it will help you :)

Comment: Hi :) thank you for that one. I tried but in my case it didn't change anything. Maybe I did something wrong. My teammate helped me today with making a small walkaround. I edited that onValueChange method which you can see in html.file. onValueChange(value: any) before looked that way: if(value !== this.item.value) { this.item.value.setValue(value); Now there is also this.setFormControlValue() at the end and the proper attribute flag of removed item switches to item which became marked as default.